# Bash script: filter columns based on a character

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My text file should be of two columns separated by a tab-space (represented by `\t`) as shown below. However, there are a few corrupted values where column 1 has two values separated by a space (represented by `\s`).

```
A\t1
B\t2
C\sx\t3
D\t4
E\sy\t5
```

My objective is to create a table as follows:

```
A\t1
B\t2
C\t3
D\t4
E\t5
```

i.e. discard the 2nd value that is present after the space in column 1 for eg. in `C\sx\t3` I can discard the `x` that is present after space and store the columns as `C\t3`.

I have tried a couple of things but with no luck.

I tried to cut the cols based on `\t` into independent columns and then cut the first column based on `\s` and join them again. However, it did not work.
Here is the snippet:

```
col1=(cut -d$'\t' -f1 $file | cut -d' ' -f1)
col2=(cut -d$'\t' -f1 $file)
myArr=()
for((idx=0;idx<${#col1[@]};idx++));do
  echo "@{col1[$idx]} @{col2[$idx]}"
  # I will append to myArr here
done
```

The output is appending the list of col2 to the col1 as `A B C D E 1 2 3 4 5`. And on top of this, my file is very huge i.e. 5,300,000 rows so I would like to avoid looping over all the records and appending them one by one.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another `sed` solution:

Search and replace any literal space followed by any number of non-TAB-characters with nothing.

```
sed -E 's/ [^\t]+//' file
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
E       5
```

If there could be more than one actual space in there just make it `'s/ +[^\t]+//'` ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you say `a space` you mean a blank character then using any awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/ .*/,"",$1)} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Perl regular expressions (for me they are easier than seds, and more portable as there are few versions of sed)

```
$ cat ls
A   1
B   2
C x 3
D   4
E y 5

$ cat ls |perl -pe 's/^(\S+).*\t(\S+)/$1 $2/g'
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
```

This code gets all non-empty characters from the front and all non-empty characters from after \t

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sed $'s/^\\([^ \t]*\\) [^\t]*/\\1/' file
```

- The [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`) feature of Bash is used to make tab characters visible as `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

take advantage of `FS` and `OFS` and let them do all the hard work for you

```
{m,g}awk NF=NF FS='[ \t].*[ \t]' OFS='\t'

A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
```

if there's a chance of leading edge or trailing edge spaces and tabs, then perhaps

```
mawk 'NF=gsub("^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$",_)^_+!_' OFS='\t' RS='[\r]?\n'
```